# how to get all record of a 2d array through loop

Tags: php, arrays

here my code-

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($order, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
<tr>
<td>$row[][0]</td>
<td>$row[][1]</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

`$order` is a 2d array that contains 2 column each row. like $order[1][0] , $order[1][1]
$order[2][0], order[2][1] and so on...how to get each row?

Comment: If you mean `$row`, then it cannot be a 2d array. `$row` only contains one row of the database table. `$order` should be a MySQL result.

Comment: so what should I use. thats my question here.

Comment: The question is what do you really want to do? Just create an HTML table of the database records?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what $order is, but $row is 1-dimensional (as the name suggests).  It is one row from $order at a time.
Is order the result from mysql_query (resource) or is it a PHP array?

Assuming resource:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($order, MYSQL_NUM)) //you seem to be using numeric indexes only
{
  <tr>
    <td>$row[0]</td>
    <td>$row[1]</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Assuming PHP array:

```
foreach($order as $row)
{
  <tr>
    <td>$row[0]</td>
    <td>$row[1]</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Where exactly is this code?  I feel like there should either by echos around the html, or start/end php tags.  (I could be wrong, I don't really do the embedded thing)